LSTM input output shape
I want to build an LSTM model:
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='tanh', input_shape(N_PAST,N_FEATURES),return_sequences=True),tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True),tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_FEATURES)])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-5, momentum=0.9) 
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),optimizer=optimizer,metrics=["mae"])

how can I make it to have the following criteria
The input layer of your model must have an input shape of your text:
(BATCH_SIZE, N_PAST = 10, N_FEATURES = 1)

The model must have an output shape of:
(BATCH_SIZE, N_FUTURE = 10, N_FEATURES = 1)

Make sure that there are N_FEATURES = 1 neurons in the final dense
layer since the model predicts 1 feature.

Please use proper code formatting. Most probably soon you will see this formatting once the edit is accepted
